# Not receiving information from offline database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a ContactApp that I Want when the user enters the information and then taps the save button, the information is saved in a ListView. But when I press the save button, my table is created but the records (rows) return an (null) value. How to solve this problem Solve?

Thanks to those who help me!

this my code in Model

```
public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Family { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

this my code in table database, table name is Favorite

```
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Family { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
```

this my code for create table:

```
readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

database.CreateTableAsync<Favorite>().Wait();
```

this my code show data from  database:

```
    public Task<List<Favorite>> GetAsync()
    {
         return database.Table<Favorite>().ToListAsync();
    }
```

this my code save in database:

```
  public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(Favorite item)
   {
     return database.InsertAsync(item);
   }
```

this my code to save items in database(command in viewmodel)

```
 SaveCommand = new Command(async ()=> await ExecuteSaveCommand());
 async Task ExecuteSaveCommand()
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            var db = new FavoriteDataBase();
          
            var favorite = new Favorite();
         
            favorite.Name=contact.Name;
            favorite.Family=contact.Family;
            favorite.PhoneNumber=contact.PhoneNumber;
            favorite.Email=contact.Email;
            favorite.Address=contact.Address;
          
            db.SaveItemAsync(favorite);
        }
```

my ui:

```
   <Entry  Placeholder="please enter name" Text="{Binding Contact.Name}" />

   <Entry  Placeholder="please enter name" Text="{Binding Contact.Family}" />

   <Entry  Placeholder="please enter name" Text="{Binding Contact.PhoneNumber}" />

   <Entry  Placeholder="please enter name" Text="{Binding Contact.Email}" />

   <Entry  Placeholder="please enter name" Text="{Binding Contact.Address}" />
```

Comment: `ExecuteSaveCommand` is creating a `new Contact()` (which will be empty) instead of using the existing Contact that your UI is bound to.

Comment: How do I solve this problem? Can you give an example with code? @Jason

Comment: your VM already contains a `Contact` property that you are binding to.  Use that existing `Contact` instead of creating a new one